# Get graph api url

Tags: javascript, facebook

How using FB JS SDK retrieve url to graph API?

In sources it is defined here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/src/core/prelude.js#L86

But in runtime I cannot find out how to get that object. They use some tricky namespace techniques, that helps them hide all the internal methods and properties ;-)

PS: a while ago it was possible to retrieve from `FB._domain` but nowadays this object is absent.

Any ideas?

Comment: What for do you need this info …?

Comment: @CBroe: I need to get the url to the user's profile image. It is `https://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture`, but I don't want to hardcode the domain (as long as we have have it somewhere in FB object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you used to be able to access the "private" data of the sdk, but not anymore as explained in the latest [official blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> **Updates to the Javascript SDK**
>
> As announced in May, we have updated the Javascript SDK to limit the
>   publicly exposed interface. This is part of an ongoing process to
>   improve the reliability of the SDK. We have removed access to all
>   internal properties and to methods prefixed with _.
>
> If you are currently relying on accessing internal properties, please
>   refactor this so that you only rely on the publicly available (and
>   officially supported) methods listed at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/.
>
> Note that all methods not listed as part of the public API might be
>   subject to change or removal, and you should not use them directly.

The graph url should not worry you and you can treat it as a constant, if it troubles you then you can have it as a static property which is defined once and use that in your code.

Comment: I see... Well, currently I also rely on `FB.getUserId()` which looks like generic public accessor, but it is not described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/... So - I have to avoid its usage as well?!?!? :-(

Comment: I've never used it, and I just tried and got `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getUserId'`. It's good practice to avoid using undocumented properties/methods since they are not part of the "contract" and can be changed with no warning. For this specific issue, I'm curious as for why you don't just get the fb user id from the signed request?

Comment: because current function is way too far from the place with authentication. But I've found *official* way of retrieving it: `FB.getAuthResponse().userID`. PS: that's strange - I do have `FB.getUserId()` and it returns current user's id. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, the `FB.getAuthResponse` method returns the same data as the signed request, it's how you access it from javascript.